# Choice of SP version for solution with Excel Web Services and MDS

Tags: sharepoint-server, excel-web-access-webpart

I must start to provision a dev environment to create a solution on SharePoint OnPrem. I try to define first what version I could use. Then What service I should use in my SharePoint farm, but I would like to have a feedback because I’m not used to this exercise.

First, I have some functionals and no-functionals objectives for my end user:
Users need to have SharePoint site whom developer could easily customize from design view

- Users need to have many separate sections with different document
  library
- Some functionals admins must be able to manage the permission    to
  the different sections for other user.
- Users need to view or edit Excel document
- Users need to view Power BI dashboard
- Users need to manage some data in SQL database from the SharePoint
  site.

Currently I have around me lot of SharePoint 2013 farm.

My first hesitation is to start with SharePoint 2013 to stay close to the prod environment (and users used Office 2013) or if this new development could be help me to show the great value of SharePoint 2016 compare to 2013.
If I stay on SharePoint 2013:

- The main component I think implement is Excel Web Access Web Part to
  view and edit Excel document.
- I didn’t had idea to manage data from SQL database from SharePoint
  site. I heard about Master Data Services in SQL Server, but I didn’t
  really get what integration can be done with SharePoint. Anyone have
  any doc about that?

If I choose SharePoint 2016, I understood Excel Web Access Web part didn’t exist and is replaced by Excel Online and so I need now to install Office Online Server. But if I’m correct this service can run on the same server as SharePoint, so I need at least 2 different servers for my SharePoint 2016 dev farm vs 1 with my SharePoint 2013 dev farm. That correct?
For my Power BI requirement, I should configure something specifically or I could just use a webpart and embed that in HTML?

Thank for your advice, I hope have a great discussion to help me to made good choice for my development.